# Why do I get an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning even though I have a catch() function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to save a user to my database with the following code:

```
userRoutes.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.user) req.session.destroy();

    const user = new User(req.body);

    user.save()
    .then(savedUser => {
        req.session.user = savedUser._id;

        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            data: {
                firstName: savedUser.firstName,
                lastName: savedUser.lastName,
                username: savedUser.username,
                email: savedUser.email,
                dateCreated: savedUser.dataCreated,
                _id: savedUser._id
            },
        });
    })
   .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            error
        });
    });
});
```

But I still get this error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: cb is not a function`

I'm using mongoose to save the document.

Comment: Where is `res` defined? I'd expect it to be an object that is returned form the promise, and declared in the `then()` function as an argument. Am I missing something?

Comment: The entire thing is in an express route where res is defined, but that's not the issue so I didn't want to clutter the post with a bunch more lines of code.

Comment: Can you add the full error stack?

Comment: What node and mongoose version are you using?

Comment: `TypeError: cb is not a function` - I think the error is not in this code

Comment: Node v8.8.1, Mongoose: 4.11.13

Comment: I don't think the error is in the code you have in the question. I pasted it into one of my own controllers and it works fine. I assume it's a part of a bigger function. Could you add that code as well? `cb is not a function` basically means it expecting a function as callback but not receiving one.

Comment: I updated the code to include the full route although I doubt that's where the problem is

Comment: I tried the entire thing, but without the two session lines (I don't have session installed), and it worked fine for me. Only thing that I find suspicious is that you delete req.session with destroy and then try to access a member of it in the then callback. But I'm no expert in sessions so it might be correct for all I know.

Comment: Which session store are you using? Is it `connect-mongo` by any chance?

Comment: Yes, is it known to have problems with promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `connect-mongo` and I don't have Mongo installed to give it a try myself but I did take a quick look through the source code to see if I could explain the problem you're having.

It seems the latest version (2.0.0) was released 3 weeks ago. I believe this change featured in that release:

https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/commit/a8b0fd49368cfc1ea634d4245105e706d2dd98c9

This changed how it invokes callbacks.

The handling of `destroy` is here:

https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/blob/509c8732061b7786857f6b835f547980c1d81c7f/src/index.js#L292

This then calls `withCallback`, which is here:

https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/blob/509c8732061b7786857f6b835f547980c1d81c7f/src/index.js#L5

I could be completely wrong but that seems to fit your symptoms perfectly. There's a function called `cb` being invoked and it isn't checking whether it's undefined first.

A simple test would be to pass a callback function to `destroy`. This shouldn't be required, I believe it's a bug in `connect-mongo`, but it should help to confirm that this really is the source of the error you're seeing. You could further diagnose by attaching a debugger, such as the Chrome dev tools, to your Node and stepping through until you hit the error.

If this does turn out to be the problem then I suggest filing a bug report with `connect-mongo`. From a quick look through the source code for some of the other session stores it does look like it's standard practice to check whether the callback is undefined before trying to call it.

I would add that I don't think `destroy` is the method you should be using here anyway. I suspect you want `regenerate`. However I believe this is a separate problem and not what's causing your current error.

I'd also note that while I stated it isn't required to pass a callback to `destroy`, `regenerate`, etc., it would still be a good idea as you should really wait for that to complete (or possibly fail) before you continue.

Comment: Thanks, I only have a vague understanding of sessions so I just copied req.session.destroy from somewhere without stopping to realize that it's probably asynchronous